# Freebase get all information from about 10 ids using php

Tags: php, json, freebase

Maybe its a pretty simple question but i didn't find a answer in the web.
I'am using the freebase v1 search php api.
Now i want to get more than 1 result per request.
I want to have all information about 10 ids in a json file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Mind supplying the code you're using mate?

Comment: I am using this: `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=1&query=Barack%20Obama&indent=true&output=(all)&lang=en`. In the result are some ids which content I want get.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query you provided, simply change the `limit` parameter to what you want. (`10` in your question)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=10&query=Barack%20Obama&inde‌​nt=true&output=(all)&lang=e
```

That will get you the results you want.

Comment: Sorry this is not what i want to do. I have from this result about 10 ids and i want to have all information about the 10 ids.

Comment: So you simple have to `json_decode()` it and then iterate through the results?

Comment: No, I want to make a request to have all information about the 10 ids. The information about the ids are not in my first request.